# Do equal components need to have different GUIDs over versions in Wix?

Tags: wix

We have many files in our application. Each file is put in a component. Do the GUIDs of these components/files needs to be different for different versions of the software? Now we always create new GUIDs for every release...

So in version 1.0:

```
<Component Id="cmpDE86F5F2ECC747CD5DBEEE393DF6F171" Guid="{0EFFF658-728F-48ED-9363-CCFBA2907361}">
 <File Id="fil21B022DF64AB20896A8D0D6D0A986920" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Ionic.Zip.xml" />
</Component>
```

And in version 1.1:

```
<Component Id="cmpDE86F5F2ECC747CD5DBEEE393DF6F171" Guid="{06CBD6F8-2DD5-473C-9E72-4D432C82EDD9}">
 <File Id="fil21B022DF64AB20896A8D0D6D0A986920" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Ionic.Zip.xml" />
</Component>
```

So is this required, or can the GUIDs stay the same over versions (even if the target file changes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the GUIDS can stay the same, even if the target file changes. That's what I usually do. In fact, it seems quite odd that you generate them new all the time.

As for right now, I can think of one scenario where this might be important:

Imagine you creating a minor upgrade(it's doing REINSTALL), and if you change GUIDS every time, it won't do much tracking. If you then change target file and GUID, you will have legacy files on your system(as in previous ones). However, if you don't change GUID, installer will be able to see that previous COMPONENTS file has changed, and do necessary moves.